# Front-end add post current date is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am using acf_form() function to add/update posts frm the front-end. Everything works fine except the post date. Somehow it is posting a very old date (1970/01/01). I wanted to post the current date instead. Here is my code:

```
    $current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    acf_form_head();
    acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_title'    => true,
        'post_content'  => true,
        'submit_value'  => __("Send", 'acf'),
        'updated_message' => __("Suksess!", 'acf'),
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'nyhet',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_category' => '',
            'post_modified' => $current_datetime,
            'post_modified_gmt' => $current_datetime,
        ),
        'fields'        => array('ingress', 'publisere_kun_pa_lokallagssiden', 'featured_image'),
        'html_submit_button' => '<input type="submit" class="button box-button green save-content" value="%s" />',
    ));
```

I know that I don't need to set 'post_modified' and 'post_modified_gmt' values if it is for the current date. I tried without those 2, then I tried setting current datetime manually. But it always inserted that weird old date. I am having same problem for updating a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a number of date/time functions

https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

you should need is:

```
acf_form_head();
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'post_title'    => true,
    'post_content'  => true,
    'submit_value'  => __("Send", 'acf'),
    'updated_message' => __("Suksess!", 'acf'),
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => 'nyhet',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_category' => '',
        'post_modified' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
        'post_modified_gmt' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
    ),
    'fields'        => array('ingress', 'publisere_kun_pa_lokallagssiden', 'featured_image'),
    'html_submit_button' => '<input type="submit" class="button box-button green save-content" value="%s" />',
));
```

for more info :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/

Comment: This does not work either. Still posting the 1970 date.

Comment: You can also use current_time('timestamp')

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 1970/01/01 is your system date. Check out your configuration.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> Function **date** returns a string formatted according to the given format string using
>   the given integer timestamp or the current system time if no timestamp is
>   given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value
>   of time().

Comment: No it's not my system date, I checked that. And also same thing happens in a live server.